# Postgres | function to sort a custom type array

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms

I have (after group by clause) the next table:

```
country | tuple
--------------------------------
England | {"(5,666)","(3,333)"} 

USA     | {"(3,222)","(2,777)"}

India   | {"(2,444)","(4,555)"}
```

tuple is defined with:

```
CREATE TYPE tuple AS (id bigint, op text);
```

I want to write a `funcion` that will sort each array of tuple by the op field, so the result will be:

```
country | tuple
--------------------------------
England | {"(5,666)","(3,333)"} 

USA     | {"(2,777)","(3,222)"}

India   | {"(4,555)","(2,444)"}
```

I tried with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_sort (ANYARRAY)
RETURNS ANYARRAY LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
      SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest($1) ORDER BY 1 desc)
$$;
```

But it didn't do the trick, any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE to unnest and order the `tuple` records and in the outer query regroup them, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_sort (ANYARRAY)
RETURNS ANYARRAY LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
  WITH j AS (SELECT unnest($1) AS op ORDER BY (unnest($1)).op DESC)
  SELECT array_agg(op) FROM j
$$;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3bb8388026ab9b40fc4cdd2241f07972)